# How to fix tile size not following set parameters?

Tags: rendering, tilesize

I noticed that tiles in my renders in Blender have been consistently at 40. I have them set at 256 by default. It started after I tried the Auto Tile add on. When I noticed it, I disabled it right away. But my renders stayed at 40. I have tried to reset to factory settings and restarted Blender but it ist still rendering at 40 tiles. I am using GTX 1660 by the way and it render fine with multiple tiles last night.

Edit: I have also tried reinstalling it but it rendered at the same tile count -- 40.

Comment: And you have tried re-adjusting the tile size after you disabled the addon?

Comment: Yes. I tried clicking the tiles and set it to both 256 pressed enter. When I rendered the animation, it was still rendering at 40 tiles.

Comment: Hmm, I might uninstall the addon. Note that uninstalling blender may not have done that.

Comment: Notably, on a GPU, wouldn’t 45 be a good size? Why try to avoid it?

Comment: I thought GPU is good with big tile size and CPU is good with small ones. I tried a smaller tile size like 64 and 128 and it fixed it for some reason.

Comment: maybe I’ve got it mixed up. I remembered it the other way around, relying on the memory being typically smaller in a GPU than the main PC ram. Will check the blender docs…

Comment: Yes, yes. Thank you for your reply!